# Synonomize tag RSV2

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

RSV2 is commonly used to search for Rainbow Six Vegas 2.

No one has used either tag before, so someone removed RSv2 tag and recommended I post on meta to synonomize the two (whatever that means).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the proper course of action is to propose a synonym:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/rainbow-6-vegas-2/synonyms

But anyway, I just went ahead and added the synonym.

Comment: I thought you could only suggest synonyms if you have enough rep in the tag

Comment: @murgatroid99 That's correct: you need 2,500 reputation and 5 score in the tag to suggest, and it requires 5 score in the tag to vote on it. Currently, [there's only one person](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/rainbow-6-vegas-2/topusers) who can do the latter, and nobody who can do the former. Bringing it to meta was the correct course of action.

Comment: @MarkTrapp huh, didn't realize that. Thanks Mark :)